# Count number of checkstyle errors in repository ignoring suppressions file

Tags: java, maven, checkstyle, maven-checkstyle-plugin

I have a maven application. In pom.xml it has a `maven-checkstyle-plugin` 3.1.1 configured with `suppressions.xml` file.

I need to count the number of checkstyle errors in the code **ignoring the suppressions.xml** file.

Is there a way to do it via command line?

For now I have come up with the following:

```
mvn clean checkstyle:checkstyle 
    -Dcheckstyle.config.location=http://example.com/checkstyle.xml
    -Dcheckstyle.config.logViolationsToConsole=true
    -Dcheckstyle.includeResources=false
    -Dcheckstyle.includeTestResources=false
```

or

```
mvn clean org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:3.1.1:checkstyle
    -Dcheckstyle.config.location=http://example.com/checkstyle.xml
    -Dcheckstyle.config.logViolationsToConsole=true
    -Dcheckstyle.includeResources=false
    -Dcheckstyle.includeTestResources=false
```

but it still takes suppressions.xml into account.

Answer (score 1):

There is no good way to do that, but there is a workaround

1. Replace checkstyle suppression file location with property (e.g. checkstyle.suppressions)
2. Create suppressions file with 0 suppressions, like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!DOCTYPE suppressions PUBLIC
    "-//Checkstyle//DTD SuppressionFilter Configuration 1.2//EN"
    "https://checkstyle.org/dtds/suppressions_1_2.dtd">

<suppressions>
</suppressions>
```

3. Set property from step 1 to path to this "empty" file. Cli options override values in pom.xml

Also, you can replace path to suppressions file in checkstyle config and override it with property in same way.

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to be working. Looks like neither `-Dcheckstyle.config.location` nor `-Dcheckstyle.suppressions.location` is not taken into account

Comment: have you tried overriding this one? https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/checkstyle-mojo.html#suppressionsFileExpression

Comment: Could you please the possible value for that property?